# Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]:

Tags: ros, navigation

I am using the waypoint_nav package. When I launched the file named outdoor_waypoint_nav_sim.launch, I got the following error:

```
RLException: while processing /home/user/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/outdoor_waypoint_nav/launch/include/gazebo.launch:
while processing /home/user/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/husky_simulator/husky_gazebo/launch/husky_empty_world.launch:
while processing /home/user/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/husky_simulator/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: no such command [['/opt/ros/noetic/share/xacro/xacro.py', '/home/user/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/husky_customization/husky_custom_gazebo/urdf/custom_description.gazebo.xacro', 'laser_enabled:=true', 'ur5_enabled:=false', 'kinect_enabled:=false']]. 

Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(arg husky_gazebo_description)'     laser_enabled:=$(arg laser_enabled)     ur5_enabled:=$(arg ur5_enabled)     kinect_enabled:=$(arg kinect_enabled)     "/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the robot description is not getting specified. Looking at the error, it's complaining when this attempts to execute:

https://github.com/nickcharron/waypoint_nav/blob/4c8bb70bd376e776c821fc659f492c55b89a342b/husky_simulator/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch#L35

I'm assuming it's because `husky_gazebo_description` is not specified. It's expecting that to be set in an environment variable called `HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION`:

https://github.com/nickcharron/waypoint_nav/blob/4c8bb70bd376e776c821fc659f492c55b89a342b/husky_simulator/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch#L32

There are two env hooks that seem to set that variable (used GH search):

https://github.com/nickcharron/waypoint_nav/blob/4c8bb70bd376e776c821fc659f492c55b89a342b/husky_simulator/husky_gazebo/env-hooks/50.husky_gazebo.sh
https://github.com/nickcharron/waypoint_nav/blob/4c8bb70bd376e776c821fc659f492c55b89a342b/husky_customization/husky_custom_gazebo/env-hooks/60.husky_custom_gazebo.sh

So then without knowing more, I am wondering if you perhaps just didn't build your workspace? Or perhaps you didn't source the workspace once it was built? I also note that you are using ROS noetic; perhaps the package hasn't been updated to support it yet. In any case, the package author suggests that you can e-mail him directly in the [README](https://github.com/nickcharron/waypoint_nav/tree/4c8bb70bd376e776c821fc659f492c55b89a342b).

Comment: thanks for your response. I have built the workspace successfully and sourced the workspace. Could you please tell me how can I set husky_gazebo_description in the environment variable which you mentioned?

Comment: I provided two links to shell scripts that appear to do that for you. Beyond that, I'd recommend you reach out to the package's author. Normally ROS etiquette dictates that you don't directly contact package authors, but this one appears to specifically suggest it.